# Renaming Layers in Deep Learning Decreases the Accuracy Rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have used Keras to implemente two deep learning models. The two models resulted high accuracy rate. Also, I created a multi input model which concatenate the two models together, but I got this error

```
RuntimeError: ('The name "block1_conv1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
```

So, I have renamed the layers in the second model:

```
for layer in model2.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("2")
```

After renaming the layers in the second model, the accuracy of the second model is decrease. When I remove the code of renaming, the second model produce a 
high accuracy. There is no difference in the structure of the second model before and after renaming the layers of the model. But I do not **why the performance of the second model is changed after renaming the layers**!.

Also, I have tried to rename the first model only, and I faced the same problem.

**Do you have any solution to solve this problem?**

**Is there another way to change the layers names?**

```
model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3))
in = model.input
out = model.output

model2 = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3))
in2 = model2.input
out2 = model2.output

for layer in model2.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("2")

merged = concatenate([out, out2])
merged = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(merged)

model_fusion = Model([in, in], merged)
```

Comment: hi @Noran, have you figured out this issue?